# Android market search by publisher broken?

Tags: android

Many apps just broke, perhaps google changed something? The documentation at http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/publishing.html says that

```
  <URI_prefix>search?q=pub:<publisher_name>
```

should work, and was working until very recently. Is anyone else having problems with this? Using a market:// link? It is giving No Results Found, and I tried for other publishers also. Is something wrong with my Google Play app perhaps, or is this affecting everyone?
Perhaps they broke something moving over to Google Play?

Thank You

Answer (score 7):

**UPDATE: The documentation seems to have been [fixed](http://developer.android.com/distribute/tools/promote/linking.html#OpeningPublisher) now.** *Thanks to @Meh for pointing that out in his comment.*

> To create the link, you need to know your *publisher name*, which is
>   available from the [Developer Console](https://play.google.com/apps/publish/).
>
> From a web site:
>
> > http://play.google.com/store/search?q=pub:
>
> From an
>   Android app:
>
> > `market://search?q=pub:<publisher_name>`
>
> Here's an example:
>
> > [https://play.google.com/store/search?q=pub:Google Inc.](https://play.google.com/store/search?q=pub:Google%20Inc.)
>
> For details on how to send the link in an Android app, see [Linking
>   from an Android App](http://developer.android.com/distribute/tools/promote/linking.html#android-app).

**PREVIOUS ANSWER:**

I found what was causing your trouble. When using a publishers name specifically, it now needs to be case sensitive. For instance, this works: http://play.google.com/store/search?q=pub:Zynga

but this doesn't: http://play.google.com/store/search?q=pub:zynga

However, if you're just searching for zynga generically, it still works even when your search term is all lower case. http://play.google.com/store/search?q=zynga

The behavior is so inconsistent now. I'd say this is a bug (or if not a bug, this quirky behavior should at least be clarified in the documentation).

Comment: Thanks. That didn't solve it, but is good to know. The problem is effecting market:// protocol URL only, not http in the browser on the device. I don't know if it is my device or just GOogle Play side. I recently put a new ROM on it that perhaps that broke something client side.

Comment: @SeanA.O.Harney I had this problem and the answer here solved it for me, correctly casing the publisher name has solved my problem. Thanks.

Comment: well there was a bug on android, they fixed it now, enjoy the points :)

Comment: @meh, Thanks for the reputation. I guess you might work for Google. I've updated my answer to point to the new documentation, but as far as I can tell, the behavior I documented is still the same. It's just that the official documentation is a lot clearer now because a good example is actually given. So I'm assuming you may have been referring to the observation made by Sean A.O. Harney in his comment about the inconsistent behavior between http:// and market:// In any case, this is good to know as well. Thanks again.

Comment: @StephanBranczyk Actually I contacted google developers support and they said it was a bug and they fixed it very quickly.